# C++ vector std::bad_alloc error in a program

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I was trying to sort a vector having user defined data type having two values, on the basis of one. But i get the error of bad_alloc. this is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct s{
int value;
int weight;
};

bool comp(s a , s b){
return a.value>b.value;
}

int main(){
vector <s> p;
s temp;
int n;
cin>>n;
while(n>=1){
    cin>>temp.value;
    cin>>temp.weight;
    p.push_back(temp);
}
sort(p.begin(), p.end(), comp);
vector <s> :: iterator it;
for(it = p.begin(); it != p.end();it++){
    *it = temp;
    cout<<temp.value<<endl;
}

}
```

on running :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc

can anyone help?

Comment: `while(n>=1)`, an infinite loop?

Comment: `std::vector::push_back()` reallocates memory whenever it's buffer is out of capacity. This and the infinite loop mentioned already by songyuanyao _must_ end with a `std::bad_alloc` after a sufficient number of iterations. What I do not understand: How do you provide so much input data that the "out of memory" (aka bad_alloc) can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems that I see:

**Infinite loop**

In the loop

```
while ( n >= 1)
{
   ...
}
```

you are not changing the value of `n`. If `n` is greater `1` than at start of the loop, the loop will never end.

**Not checking the status of input**

You have

```
 cin >> temp.value;
 cin >> temp.weight;
```

You are not checking whether those calls succeeded. You are assuming that they did and proceeding to use `temp`.

**Wrong way assignment**

In the final loop, you are using

```
*it = temp;
```

That will change the `vector`, not extract the value from the vector.

---

Here's an updated version of `main` that should work.

```
int main()
{
   vector <s> p;
   s temp;
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   while(n>=1)
   {
      // If there is a problem reading, break.
      if ( !(cin>>temp.value) )
      {
         break;
      }

      // If there is a problem reading, break.
      if ( !(cin>>temp.weight) )
      {
         break;
      }

      p.push_back(temp);

      // Decrement n
      --n;
   }

   sort(p.begin(), p.end(), comp);
   vector <s> :: iterator it;
   for(it = p.begin(); it != p.end();it++)
   {
      // Extract the value from the vector and print it.
      temp = *it;
      cout<<temp.value<<endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters a value of 1 or higher for `n`, the loop never ends, filling the vector until it uses up all available memory. You are not decrementing `n` on each loop iteration so the loop eventually breaks:

```
while (n >= 1) {
    cin >> temp.value;
    cin >> temp.weight;
    p.push_back(temp);
    --n; // <-- add this
}
```

In this situation, a `for` loop would be more appropriate than a `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> temp.value;
    cin >> temp.weight;
    p.push_back(temp);
}
```

I would go as far as getting rid of the manual loop altogether by defining a custom `operator>>` for `struct s` and then use `std::copy_n()` with `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

istream& operator>>(istream &in, s &out) {
    in >> out.value;
    in >> out.weight;
    return in;
}    

int main() {
    ...
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    copy_n(istream_iterator<s>(cin), n, back_inserter(p));
    ...
}
```

Any way you fill the vector, your `comp` function should take its input parameters by reference:

```
bool comp(s &a, s &b) {
    return a.value > b.value;
}
```

Also, your output loop is not using the iterator correctly. You need to get rid of the `*it =` assignment and just output the referenced value as-is:

```
for(it = p.begin(); it != p.end(); ++it) {
    //*it = temp; // <- get rid of this
    cout << it->value << endl;
}
```